# Jacobi iteration doesn't end

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical, numerical-analysis

I'm trying to implement the Jacobi iteration in MATLAB but am unable to get it to converge. I have looked online and elsewhere for working code for comparison but am unable to find any that is something similar to my code and still works. Here is what I have:

```
function x = Jacobi(A,b,tol,maxiter)

n = size(A,1);
xp = zeros(n,1); 
x = zeros(n,1); 
k=0; % number of steps

while(k<=maxiter)
    k=k+1;

    for i=1:n
       xp(i) = 1/A(i,i)*(b(i) - A(i,1:i-1)*x(1:i-1) - A(i,i+1:n)*x(i+1:n));
    end

    err = norm(A*xp-b);

    if(err<tol)
        x=xp;
        break;
    end

    x=xp;

end
```

This just blows up no matter what A and b I use. It's probably a small error I'm overlooking but I would be very grateful if anyone could explain what's wrong because this should be correct but is not so in practice.

Comment: have you tried running your code in debug mode, checking the values of `x` and `xp` at each iteration? does your `err` decrease with iterations? at what rate?

Comment: @Mauvai What do you mean? He compares `k` to `maxiter`, and increments `k` during each iteration.

Comment: @user101368 - Your code is correct.  You are not specifying correct linear systems to solve your problem.  I have made a post for you to see.  Dennis and Mauvai - Nothing is wrong with the code.  Please read my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is correct.  The reason why it may not seem to work is because you are specifying systems that **may not** converge when you are using Jacobi iterations.

To be specific (thanks to @Saraubh), this method will converge if your matrix `A` is **strictly** [diagonally dominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).  In other words, for each row `i` in your matrix, the absolute summation of all of the columns `j` at row `i` without the diagonal coefficient at `i` must be **less** than the diagonal itself.  In other words:

[image: blah]

However, there are some systems that will converge with Jacobi, even if this condition isn't satisfied, but you should use this as a general rule before trying to use Jacobi for your system.  It's actually more stable if you use Gauss-Seidel.  The only difference is that you are re-using the solution of `x` and feeding it into the other variables as you progress down the rows.  To make this Gauss-Seidel, all you have to do is change one character within your `for` loop.  Change it from this:

```
xp(i) = 1/A(i,i)*(b(i) - A(i,1:i-1)*x(1:i-1) - A(i,i+1:n)*x(i+1:n));
```

To this:

```
xp(i) = 1/A(i,i)*(b(i) - A(i,1:i-1)*xp(1:i-1) - A(i,i+1:n)*x(i+1:n));
                                    **HERE**
```

Here are two examples that I will show you:

1. Where we specify a system that does not converge by Jacobi, but there is a solution.  This system is **not** diagonally dominant.
2. Where we specify a system that does converge by Jacobi.  Specifically, this system is diagonally dominant.

---

## Example #1

```
A = [1 2 2 3; -1 4 2 7; 3 1 6 0; 1 0 3 4];
b = [0;1;-1;2];
x = Jacobi(A, b, 0.001, 40)
xtrue = A \ b

x =

1.0e+09 *

4.1567
0.8382
1.2380
1.0983

xtrue =

-0.1979
-0.7187
 0.0521
 0.5104
```

Now, if I used the Gauss-Seidel solution, this is what I get:

```
x =

-0.1988
-0.7190
0.0526
0.5103
```

Woah!  It converged for Gauss-Seidel and not Jacobi, even though the system isn't diagonally dominant, I may have an explanation for that, and I'll provide later.

## Example #2

```
A = [10 -1 2 0; -1 -11 -1 3; 2 -1 10 -1; 0 3 -1 8];
b = [6;25;-11;15];
x = Jacobi(A, b, 0.001, 40);
xtrue = A \ b

x =

0.6729
-1.5936
-1.1612
2.3275

xtrue =

0.6729
-1.5936
-1.1612
2.3274
```

This is what I get with Gauss-Seidel:

```
x =

0.6729
-1.5936
-1.1612
2.3274
```

This certainly converged for both, and the system is diagonally dominant.

---

As such, there is **nothing** wrong with your code.  You are just specifying a system that **can't** be solved using Jacobi.  It's better to use Gauss-Seidel for iterative methods that revolve around this kind of solving.  The reason why is because you are immediately using information from the current iteration and spreading this to the rest of the variables.  Jacobi does not do this, which is the reason why it diverges more quickly.  For Jacobi, you can see that Example #1 failed to converge, while Example #2 did.  Gauss-Seidel converged for both. In fact, when they both converge, they're quite close to the true solution.

Again, you need to make sure that your systems are diagonally dominant so you are guaranteed to have convergence.  Not enforcing this rule... well... you'll be taking a risk as it may or may not converge.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh, that explains it. I was using random matrices the entire time that kept diverging. I also had a Gauss-Seidel method coded up as well and it worked perfectly fine so I was a bit confused but it just seems that my initial choice in matrices was poor. Thank you, you explained it perfectly!

Comment: Hi, It seems that even strictly diagonal dominant matrix won't guarantee convergence of the solution. See: http://pastebin.com/tBd8aXYR Though it will be Diagonal Dominant I see cases where it doesn't converge.

Comment: @Drazick - Stupid question, but did you check to see if your system has a proper inverse?  I see that you are generating a bunch of random matrices.  Random numbers may not guarantee a full rank matrix.

Comment: @Drazick - Just because a matrix is diagonally dominant also doesn't necessarily mean that your system will have a solution.  You also have to be sure that your system has a unique solution, or is full rank.  Generating a bunch of random matrices may not give you this result.  Perhaps you should try with a matrix with a known solution, and seeing if SOR will give you the right result.

Comment: @rayryeng, The matrix is full rank. Sometimes it has Condition Number which is high, yet it is still easily invertible by `inv`.

Comment: @Drazick - I'm out of ideas... other than perhaps playing around with the relaxation factor.  I honestly don't know what else to try!  Did you try other iterative methods, like Conjugate Gradient?

Comment: @rayryeng, I'm just saying this method is very picky on its working cases. I guess it only works for very well behaved cases :-).

Answer (score 1):

Though this does not point out the problem in your code, I believe that you are looking for the [Numerical Methods: Jacobi File Exchange Submission](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2181-numerical-methods-using-matlab-2e/content/edition2/matlab/chap_3/jacobi.m).

```
%JACOBI   Jacobi iteration for solving a linear system.
% Sample call
%   [X,dX] = jacobi(A,B,P,delta,max1)
%   [X,dX,Z] = jacobi(A,B,P,delta,max1)
```

It seems to do exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out that not all systems are convergent using Jacobi method, but they do not point out why? Actually only a small sub-set of systems converge with Jacobi method.

The convergence criteria is that the "sum of all the coefficients (non-diagonal) in a row" must be lesser than the "coefficient at the diagonal position in that row". This criteria must be satisfied by all the rows. You can read more at: [Jacobi Method Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Convergence)

Before you decide to use Jacobi method, you must see whether this criteria is satisfied by the numerical method or not. The Gauss-Seidel method has a slightly more relaxed convergence criteria which allows you to use it for most of the Finite Difference type numerical methods.

Comment: You may want to note that this is a necessary and not a sufficient condition.  There are some systems that will converge via Jacobi even if that inequality is not satisfied